# iPhone Photos storage error

Tags: itunes, photos, iphone, storage

I have an iPhone 6 with 16GB of storage, and it has been saying there isn't enough space on my device (mainly because I had 6,000 photos in my album with was taking up 8GB). So went on my Mac and transferred all the photos on my iPhone to my Mac, and then deleted them off my phone. It has been 2 weeks now and my phone is still continuing to say I don't have enough space, and that photos is still taking up the 8GBs of storage. 
I have tried turning my iPhone off and on trying to reset it, but nothing is working.

Comment: Are you sure you're still not syncing the photos back to your iPhone?  Check your iCloud settings to ensure it's not syncing the photos right back to the phone.

Comment: Are they still on the phone in "Recently Deleted"?

Comment: I turned my icould photo settings off before this whole process started. They are not in recently deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

1. Turn off iCloud Photo Library
2. Turn off iCloud Photo Sharing
3. Delete all those pictures
4. Delete the recently deleted folder
5. Make sure that you have no other photos in any other folder under the Albums tab
6. Force Reset your iPhone [see instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559)
7. Turn on your iPhone and verify step 5 again
8. Your storage space should be regained